Error with mysqldump in batch script when using multiple conditions in WHERE clause
I'm facing an issue with using mysqldump inside a batch script to backup a database with certain conditions. The problem arises when I add multiple condition sets inside an IN clause.
For example, the following command works fine:
mysqldump -u root -ppass --where="[some_column_name]=[somevalue] AND NAME IN ('value1','value2')" dbname tablename > [path]/filename.sql

However, when I attempt to add a large number of possible values for a column within the IN clause (say, 1000 values), I encounter an error stating that > is not recognized as a table. I suspect there might be a character limit to this command.
Here's the problematic command:
mysqldump -u root -ppass --where="[some_column_name]=[somevalue] AND NAME IN ('value1','value2',.....,'value1000')" dbname tablename > [path]/filename.sql

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

It sounds like > is escaped or in quotes in your script. I suspect it's in a variable and then you're trying to use the variable expansion as a command. Most special shell syntax is not parsed after variable expansion, so you can't do something like variable="> filename"

Please post the actual script.

hi Barmar,
i think problem is with windows or linux max allowed character in command line,
i did some research and found this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/command-line-string-limitation
it seems windows only allow 8191  character in cmd and i violate that in my mysql dump command

i am curious is there another way to bypass the 8191 character limit?

Can you use bash instead of CMD?

i do not access to a linux  , but as i learn so far on linux there is 4096 character limit wich is half of windows limitation on command line

Put the values you want to match in another table. Then use AND name IN (SELECT columnName FROM tableName)

sadly i cannot use IN (SELECT columnName FROM tableName) because the column values is dynamic between 100 to 1000 unique values and either way i should pass then dynamicaly and cannot use sql to generate them

Then I think you're screwed if you have to do this in shell. Write a program in some other language like Python or PHP.
